# javafx 2.2 webview scroll speed is slow (2d rendering)

Tags: javafx-2

JavaFX 2 WebView uses WebKit to render. My Machine doesn't have direct 3d support and I can see it in prism logs

```
Loading D3D native library ...
    succeeded.
Direct3D initialization failed
Adapter validation failed for all adapters
(X) Got class = class com.sun.prism.d3d.D3DPipeline
Prism pipeline name = com.sun.prism.j2d.J2DPipeline
(X) Got class = class com.sun.prism.j2d.J2DPipeline
Initialized prism pipeline: com.sun.prism.j2d.J2DPipeline
GraphicsPipeline.createPipeline: error initializing pipeline com.sun.prism.d3d.D3DPipeline
*** Fallback to Prism SW pipeline
```

The speed of scroll on a loaded html page is very slow. Scrolling  the same page on the same machine using Chrome (which uses WebKit as well) is fast enough.

The content of the page is mostly text. No heave java script, simple static.

Do I need to turn on some settings or it simply Prism SW pipeline is much slower then whatever is used in Chrome to draw lines and images?

*OS Windows 7*

*DirectDraw Acceleration: Not Available*
*Direct3D Acceleration: Not Available*
*AGP Texture Acceleration: Not Available*

Answer (score 2):

The Prism SW pipeline used by the JavaFX 2.2 WebView is much slower then whatever is used in Chrome to draw lines and images.

If there are particular web pages which cause slowdowns, you can log them as [JavaFX performance issues](http://javafx-jira.kenai.com).

JavaFX rendering is capped at 60fps and there is an undocumented property which can remove this cap, but you shouldn't really notice that with the naked eye anyway.

You can also switch on and off the hardware pipeline with system properties.  You aren't using the hardware pipeline right now, and it's probably because your hardware accelerator is not supported by JavaFX.  You could use the undocumented switch to force the hardware accelerated pipeline on, but that would have unforeseen consequences.

There is a [text font smoothing property](https://blogs.oracle.com/javafx/entry/lcd_text_support_in_javafx) which will probably affect WebView text rendering speed.  I'm not sure how to turn this property on and off for WebView.

For jdk8, there are numerous performance improvements in [core JavaFX rendering](http://fxexperience.com/2012/09/preliminary-performance-numbers-in-javafx-8/) as well as [WebView rendering](http://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-22913) - including things such as [shape clips](http://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-23690) and [gpu accelerated compositing](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/dev/developers/design-documents/gpu-accelerated-compositing-in-chrome) as used in Chrome.  Again, as you are running a software pipeline, you won't see the impact of hardware accelerated compositing, but you should still be able to get some performance improvements from other jdk8 modifications.  You can get a [preview version of jdk8](http://jdk8.java.net/download.html), which includes a late development version of JavaFX, and see if your performance improves.

Use the JavaFX 32 bit version if WebView performance is critical, because that version currently has the JavaScript JIT compiler switched on and the 64 bit version does not.  It won't make a difference to rendering speed, but it might impact overall perceived speed.  The release version of jdk8 will use a [new JavaScript Engine](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/announce/2012-November/000139.html) which should see performance improve for both the 32 and 64 bit releases.

Of course, if you add a compatible hardware card, then JavaFX will use an accelerated rendering path and rendering performance should also improve.

Comment: That is a lot of information. Thank you.
My video driver is limited to Citrix virtual card I guess. We use kind of virtual computers. 

The page is any page basically and when I scroll with a wheel or scroll bar I see lags. Especially when I use jquery to auto scroll which works like a charm in Chrome. I think it is a render problem and not java script related one.

I will check Java 8 for the experiment sake but I can't use it for final app.